# Unknown file generated when saving in nuxeo: WebKitFormBoundary

Tags: ecm, nuxeo

I'm new to nuxeo and trying to understand it by nuxeo university tuitorials and the nuxeo documentation.
I'm trying to upload a file and for that, I followed the [tuitorial](https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/howto-upload-file-nuxeo-using-rest-api/).

1. I generated the batch ID.
2. Uploaded the file using

> URL
>
> ```
>  http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/upload/batchId/0
> ```
>
> Headers
>
> ```
>  Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3Rybnhvcjptb2hpdC4xMjM0
>  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>  X-File-Name: licenseFile
>  X-File-Type: text/plain
> ```
>
> File
>
> ```
>  file: /var/lib/nuxeo/server/LICENSE.txt
> ```

3. Attach the uploaded file to the document.

But when I check the file in nuxeo web UI, It does not have the original content but something else:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryNyRaKLr8FB6Afcu2

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"



/var/lib/nuxeo/server/LICENSE.txt

------WebKitFormBoundaryNyRaKLr8FB6Afcu2--
```

Comment: Please update your question with the exact code you use to do the upload. Are you using `curl` for instance? Which options? The point is that you should not be posting the file name but the full file content.